# Undoing Changes in Bound Objects with C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reference

In my application I have a collection of data objects that define what types of data the application collects as it executes.

The user can open a dialog window to edit these objects and that dialog window contains DataGridView instances that are bound to the collections. This means that any changes the user makes are instantly applied, which is not good.

The other issue is that this dialog window has a Cancel button allowing the user to discard all the changes they have made since opening the window.

Currently when the window is opened I serialize all the objects (shallow copy won't work) and if the user clicks on Cancel then I deserialize them to restore them. The problem I am running into is that this is messy. It changes all the references and some of these objects store a data history as well, which isn't serialized. I then have to have events rippling out through the application to notify objects to update their references, etc. It's a pain.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: DataTable provides edit buffering. If you can work out how to populate a DataTable with your object collection, then just bind the grid to the DataTable and don't call AcceptChanges() on the table if the user cancels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* a better way, using an interface that is cooked into the framework - [IEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx)

BeginEdit
CancelEdit
EndEdit

The basic idea it that you create a snapshot of some object's state when you call BeginEdit. On CancelEdit, you roll back to that SavedState, and on EndEdit you commit it.

The devil is in the details of course. Here's a popular link that has served as an implementation answer to similar SO questions for some ideas

http://www.paulstovell.com/blog/runtime-ui-binding-behavior-ieditableobject-adapter

Cheers,
Berryl

NOTE: this isn't conceptually different to what tocco is saying, and you should give him the answer. BUT worth spelling out in a separate answer because it formalizes the concept in a .Net idiomatic way and offers more insight into a useful implementation. Besides, it is good fun saying the word idiomatic :--)

Comment: I don't think Tocco's answer takes into account references throughout the application to objects inside the collection. This looks more suitable for my needs - I'll look a bit closer. Thanks!

Comment: Upvote because "idiomatic" IS fun to say! :)  ... oh, and because it's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an original version and a copy of your object or a copy of your entire collection.
So you can edit the copy and save to perform the changes or cancel to preserve the original object/collection.

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6630566/830523)

Comment: If I make a copies and the user edits the copies then clicks on OK don't I have the same problem as I currently do? Namely all the object references will now need to be updated throughout the application? It's that issue I would like to avoid. Or do you mean that when the user clicks on OK I should copy the changes over including deleting removed objects and adding new objects?

Comment: @Andy, if you make a copy `b` of the collection `a`, you can allow the user to edit the copy `b`, if he clicks on OK, you should set `a = b`. If he clicks on Cancel, you should discard `b`. That's the idea.

Comment: What about all the references to objects inside the collection? Those will change won't they? Note that the user can edit the objects themselves, not just add/delete from the collection.

Comment: If you are making a "copy" of your collection they will not change. Because the new collection will have new objects with the same "values".